# Reading a specific line from a text file

Tags: php, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting one line in a huge file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794056/getting-one-line-in-a-huge-file-with-php)

I have a file text with something like 200 lines and I want to read a specific line from this text file. how can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested.

```
function getline($file, $linenum, $linelen = 8192) {
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $linenum -= 1;
            $buffer = fgets($handle, $linelen); // Read a line.
            if (!$linenum) return $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handle); // Close the file.
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Suppressing errors on an fopen and then presuming all is well - classy. (Also love to know what the quotes are for around the "$file" on the fopen line.)

Comment: Ahh woops, the quote and @ were an error because I copypasted the basecode from somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this is a duplicate, but anyway:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt');
$file->seek($lineNumber); // zero based
echo $file->current();
```

*marking CW because middaparka found the duplicate*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it - keep reading lines from a file until you get the one you want (the last line makes sure we return false if we didn't find the line we wanted.

```
function getLine($file, $lineno)
{
    $line=false;
    $fp=fopen($file, 'r');
    while (!feof($fp) && $lineno--)
    {
        $line=fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($file);
    return ($lineno==0)?$line:false;

}
```

Comment: Go on - add a is_resource($fp) check in there - you *know you want to*. :-)