# How to extract data in " " using PHP?

Tags: php, extract

```
local szMsg = string.format("    歡迎來到非常劍俠有獎問答，您隻需交納%s就可以參加本次有獎答題，隻要您能回答正確<color=yellow>%s個<color>關於劍俠世界的小問題，就會獲得%s，如果中途答錯或者自己選擇退出，不僅沒有獎勵，您交納的%s也不會退還。怎麼樣，要參加嗎？", szNeedMoney, self.tbGroup[nGroupId].nQuestionMax, szAwardMsg, szNeedMoney);
local tbOpt =
```

I want to extract the data between the `" "` from my file using PHP.

Comment: What do you mean extract? What are you trying to do? And what is your question?

Comment: Yeah i want get the value beetwen " " to change and edit languague

Comment: Do you mean quote marks in the file?

Comment: @Dagon, no i know this function , but now i want get only the data beetwen " " ; Thanks for your help

Comment: @Daniel , yes i want get the data in quote marks in this file

Comment: Then David's solution below should do the trick.

Comment: Presuming there is only one set of quote marks. Otherwise, it will just get the first set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $string = ' local szMsg =
>   string.format("歡迎來到非常劍俠有獎問答，您隻需交納%s就可以參加本次有獎答題，隻要您能回答正確%s個關於劍俠世界的小問題，就會獲得%s，如果中途答錯或者自己選擇退出，不僅沒有獎勵，您交納的%s也不會退還。怎麼樣，要參加嗎？",
>   szNeedMoney, self.tbGroup[nGroupId].nQuestionMax, szAwardMsg,
>   szNeedMoney); local tbOpt =" ';
>   preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $out); 
>   $output = str_replace('"', "", $out[0]); 
>   echo $output;

This will output:

```
歡迎來到非常劍俠有獎問答，您隻需交納%s就可以參加本次有獎答題，隻要您能回答正確<color=yellow>%s個<color>關於劍俠世界的小問題，就會獲得%s，如果中途答錯或者自己選擇退出，不僅沒有獎勵，您交納的%s也不會退還。怎麼樣，要參加嗎？
```

because it's inside the double quotes in $string;

Put your data as $string and you're done!

Comment: Hello david. Can i ask if i want preg_match_all in a file with this code : http://comicvn.net/ex.txt

Comment: You need to use `file_get_contents();` if it's a remote file.

Comment: If you have a really long file like that, you can use the $out array to get all the instances of the quotes. Or, you can use something like this to search for the line first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794073/1415625

Comment: Look at comment with the link in it. It will search by line and then you can perform the regex on it

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
preg_match('/"(.+)"/',$string,$matches); // puts text into $matches[1]
```