# getInputStream in PHP

Tags: php, jsp, inputstream

I have a page written in `JSP` (that I don't know) that I need to understand and analyse whether the page can be written in another format (PHP/ASP etc).

I came across the following in the file:

```
BufferedReader myRequest = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"))
```

After searching I believe the `getInputStream` method is reading the request body of the request in binary format.

If that's correct, is this possible too in PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: similar functionality in php read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970632/php-how-to-read-big-remote-files-efficiently-and-use-buffer-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `getInputStream()` is used to get the body of the request. Thus, you will only get the body of the request, not the whole thing.

Please have a look [`getinputstream()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?330039-how-can-i-open-inputstream-from-php) for knowing more about its functioning in php.
You can use [`http_get_request_body()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) for the same purpose which requests the body as a string type.