# How fix Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated ) (tried to allocate bytes) in php

Tags: php

I read value of a file csv as:

```
 //$mypath . '/' . $filename <=> ../abc.csv
 $val = file_get_contents($mypath . '/' . $filename);                                       

 $escaped = pg_escape_bytea($val);

 $model->addFileImport($tmp, $data['email'], $escaped);
```

My file ia about 100MB.
In php.ini setting :
memory_limit = 128M

But it still show errort`:Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133120 bytes) in...` at row:   `$val = file_get_contents($mypath . '/' . $filename);`

I had fixed by add   `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`:

```
 //$mypath . '/' . $filename <=> ../abc.csv
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
 $val = file_get_contents($mypath . '/' . $filename);                                       

 $escaped = pg_escape_bytea($val);

 $model->addFileImport($tmp, $data['email'], $escaped);
```

But it show error :

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 230686720) (tried to allocate 657099991 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\joomlandk\components\com_servicemanager\views\i0701\view.html.php on line 112

at row `$escaped = pg_escape_bytea($val);`

Why? How fix that error?

Comment: You ran out of memory, physical memory as far as I can tell. 657099991  bytes is 626.659 Megabytes. You best bet is to [use a bigger swap file](https://www.google.com/search?q=increase+size+of+swap+file).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-bytea.php)

> pg_escape_bytea() escapes string for bytea datatype. It returns
> escaped string.
>
> When you SELECT a bytea type, PostgreSQL returns octal byte values
> prefixed with '' (e.g. **\032**). Users are supposed to convert back to
> binary format manually.

meaning a single input byte gives 4 bytes, i.e. 4 times the initial size

You need a lot of RAM to handle your file (maybe your system cannot allocate that much memory - even without the PHP limit). A solution is to process it from 40MB chunks, made, for instance with [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and [fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) functions.

```
  $val = file_get_contents($mypath . '/' . $filename);
```

will take 100MB - thus the next line takes 400 MB, total 500MB. You need to read less from *file_get_contents*, like reading only 20 (or 40) MB at a time

- Read 20MB of the file with *fread* (instead of file_get_contents)
- process that 20MB with *pg_escape_bytea* (total 100MB)
- Repeat the process until the file is fully processed

Comment: But it show error at row :  $escaped = pg_escape_bytea($val);
I must convert string to bytea Insert to database.

Comment: Yes because the 1st line *file_get_contents* takes 100MB, then the *pg_escape_bytea* line takes 4 times, ie 400MB. Total 500MB... This is why the error comes there - if you could *file_get_contents* only (say) 25MB, the total would be only 125MB. See the edit

Comment: Can i set memeory for webserver?

Comment: @mum please refer to [How to save memory when reading a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603807/how-to-save-memory-when-reading-a-file-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '700M');
```

Comment: it show error:  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 734003200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 657099991 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\joomlandk\components\com_servicemanager\views\i0701\view.html.php on line 114:  $val = file_get_contents($mypath . '/' . $filename);