# optimizing memory resources for a big query response

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have to perform a query that can generates a very big string in response (up to 1Gb), which is basically a big, big JSON array. Yes, pagination is in order but I'm stressing the concept in order to get you the idea. 
Symfony simply uses doctrine to get the response:

```
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare(self::Q_GET_NUM_TIMEBOX);

    $stmt->bindValue('t_end', $tEnd);
    $stmt->bindValue('t_granularity', $tGranularity);
    $stmt->bindValue('t_span', $varSelection->getStart());

    $stmt->execute();

    $resData = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```

and then I create a `Response` by setting the content I had in return from the execute.

```
    $res = new Response();
    $res->setStatusCode(200);
    $res->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $res->setContent($resData);
```

Keep in mind I oversimplified the code for the sake of clarity: I actually have a  `controller`,  a `handler` service performing the request and a `Repository` returning the query response.

Back straight to the problem: this implies that PHP must hold that big amount of data in memory and I was wondering if there was an lighter way to return the response in order to stress less PHP engine with big amount of data.

Comment: use a StreamedResponse in conjunction with an iterable query result

Comment: @Matteo that still does not directly solve the problem of encoding this data to JSON.

Comment: @Gerry no need of encoding. Postgres returns a string well-encoded already. Basically a function  I wrote generates and returns it

Comment: Ic, I misunderstood that from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this implies that PHP must hold that big amount of data

PHP is not required to keep in the memory a whole response body. Through [output buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) and Symfony [response streaming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) you can fetch result set row-by-row and send a data by chunks. Unfortunately I don't known well-tried solution for JSON stream encoding in PHP, but you can implement it manually ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32845069/1220930), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36446924/1220930)).

*Update (2017-02-27):*

> [Streaming JSON Encoder](https://github.com/violet-php/streaming-json-encoder) is a PHP library that provides a set of classes to help with encoding JSON in a streaming manner, i.e. allowing you to encode the JSON document bit by bit rather than encoding the whole document at once.